# CAML query case sensitive search

Tags: xml, sharepoint

I have a caml query which is pulling data from sharepoint list

Here is the query I am using

tempQuery = "John"+CURRENT_USER_Info.currFilter+"";

The problem is I have search only for John and not john or JOHN

so basically looking for a caml query which can filter case sensitively..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only case sensitive part of a CAML query is the CAML syntax

Answer (score 6):

There is no option for case sensitivity in caml queries. You must filter the results secondary for case sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I was able to find another condition for this caml query but not sure on how to implement the nested query. A combination of ors and in one of the Ors there should be an AND in between

Answer (score 2):

It is true that straight CAML queries are case-insensitive, but you may be able to use LINQ to SharePoint to get to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I was able to find another condition for this caml query but not sure on how to implement the nested query. A combination of ors and in one of the Ors there should be an AND in between